# Use of Ninject as an IoC container in a WinForms MVC application

Tags: c#, mvc, winforms, dependency-injection, ninject

I am a relatively experienced WPF developer who has had good exposure to MVVM. I have been developing legacy WinForms applications for a while and have recently been asked to fully re-write a large one.

To do this I want to use TDD and in order to facilitate this and make the application as extensible as possible going forwards (opposite to what the old one was), I want to incorporate Dependency Injection and use the MVC pattern.

I would like some guidance on a few things:

1. Is my use of Ninject for the DI Container proper and correct?
2. Is my use of MVC proper and correct?
3. How could I improve my code?

**Program.cs** (the main entry point of the WinForms application):

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        FileLogHandler fileLogHandler = new FileLogHandler(Utils.GetLogFilePath());
        Log.LogHandler = fileLogHandler;
        Log.Trace("Program.Main(): Logging initialized");

        CompositionRoot.Initialize(new DependencyModule());
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(CompositionRoot.Resolve<ApplicationShellView>());
    }
}
```

**DependencyModule.cs**

```
public class DependencyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IApplicationShellView>().To<ApplicationShellView>();

        Bind<IDocumentController>().To<SpreadsheetController>();
        Bind<ISpreadsheetView>().To<SpreadsheetView>();
    }
}
```

**CompositionRoot.cs**

```
public class CompositionRoot
{
    private static IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public static void Initialize(INinjectModule module)
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(module);
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return ninjectKernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return ninjectKernel.GetAll<T>();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationShellView.cs** (the main form of the application)

```
public partial class ApplicationShellView : C1RibbonForm, IApplicationShellView
{
    private ApplicationShellController controller; 

    public ApplicationShellView()
    {
        this.controller = new ApplicationShellController(this);
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeView();
    }

    public void InitializeView()
    {
        dockPanel.Extender.FloatWindowFactory = new CustomFloatWindowFactory();
        dockPanel.Theme = vS2012LightTheme;
    }

    private void ribbonButtonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.OpenNewSpreadsheet();
    }

    public DockPanel DockPanel
    {
        get { return dockPanel; }
    }
}
```

Where:

```
public interface IApplicationShellView
{
    void InitializeView();

    DockPanel DockPanel { get; }
}
```

**ApplicationShellController.cs**

```
public class ApplicationShellController
{
    private IApplicationShellView shellView;
    private List<IDocumentController> documentControllerCache = new List<IDocumentController>();

    [Inject]
    public ApplicationShellController(IApplicationShellView view)
    {
        this.shellView = view;
    }

    public void OpenNewSpreadsheet(DockState dockState = DockState.Document)
    {
        SpreadsheetController controller = (SpreadsheetController)GetDocumentController("new.xlsx");
        SpreadsheetView view = (SpreadsheetView)controller.New("new.xlsx");
        view.Show(shellView.DockPanel, dockState);
        documentControllerCache.Add(controller);
    }

    private IDocumentController GetDocumentController(string path)
    {
        return CompositionRoot.ResolveAll<IDocumentController>()
            .Cast<IDocumentController>()
            .Where(provider => provider.Handles(path))
            .Select(provider => provider)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IApplicationShellView ShellView { get { return shellView; } }
}
```

**SpreadsheetController.cs**

```
public class SpreadsheetController : IDocumentController 
{
    private ISpreadsheetView view;

    public SpreadsheetController(ISpreadsheetView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.SetController(this);
    }

    public bool Handles(string path)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
        {
            if (FileTypes.Any(ft => ft.FileExtension.CompareNoCase(extension)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void SetViewActive(bool isActive)
    {
        ((SpreadsheetView)view).ShowIcon = isActive;
    }

    public IDocumentView New(string fileName)
    {
        // Opens a new file correctly.
    }

    public IDocumentView Open(string path)
    {
        // Opens an Excel file correctly.
    }

    public IEnumerable<DocumentFileType> FileTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<DocumentFileType>()
            {
                new DocumentFileType("CSV",  ".csv" ),
                new DocumentFileType("Excel", ".xls"),
                new DocumentFileType("Excel10", ".xlsx")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Where the implemented interface is:

```
public interface IDocumentController
{
    bool Handles(string path);

    void SetViewActive(bool isActive);

    IDocumentView New(string fileName);

    IDocumentView Open(string path);

    IEnumerable<DocumentFileType> FileTypes { get; }
}
```

Now the view ascociated with this controller is:

```
public partial class SpreadsheetView : DockContent, ISpreadsheetView
{
    private IDocumentController controller;

    public SpreadsheetView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SpreadsheetView_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SetViewActive(true);
    }

    private void SpreadsheetView_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SetViewActive(false);
    }

    public void SetController(IDocumentController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
        Log.Trace("SpreadsheetView.SetController(): Controller set successfully");
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value; }
    }

    public WorkbookView WorkbookView
    {
        get { return workbookView; }
        set { workbookView = value; }
    }

    public bool StatusBarVisible
    {
        get { return statusStrip.Visible; }
        set { statusStrip.Visible = value; }
    }

    public string StatusMessage
    {
        get { return statusLabelMessage.Text; }
        set { statusLabelMessage.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

The view interfaces are:

```
public interface ISpreadsheetView : IDocumentView
{
    WorkbookView WorkbookView { get; set; } 
}
```

And:

```
public interface IDocumentView
{
    void SetController(IDocumentController controller);

    string DisplayName { get; set; }

    bool StatusBarVisible { get; set; }
}
```

All this code works and "feels okay". But I am not experienced with either MVC (at least not using WinForms) or Ninject/DI (I have used MEF extensively, but that is slightly difference that what Ninject does).

Note: I am implementing `IDocumentView` because I want to also open and dock other types of documents (code and text etc.).

Could you provide and guidance as to what I have done so far and answer the questions above?

Comment: If you'd like further review, post a new follow-up question.

Comment: Please provide me time to edit my own question. Due to lack of rollback privileges on this site, I have had to copy the html and re-format costing me time.

Comment: @Killercam You can always look at the revision history and get the source of your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels a bit awkward:

> ```
> public class CompositionRoot
> {
>     private static IKernel ninjectKernel;
>
>     public static void Initialize(INinjectModule module)
>     {
>         ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(module);
>     }
>
>     public static T Resolve<T>()
>     {
>         return ninjectKernel.Get<T>();
>     }
>
>     public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>()
>     {
>         return ninjectKernel.GetAll<T>();
>     }
> }
> ```

As I understand it, an application's *composition root* is simply *where composition occurs* - ideally as close as possible to the entry point. This class doesn't encapsulate a "composition root", it merely wraps an `IKernel` and ultimately deprives the actual composition root from all the flexibility and power that Ninject offers, by literally forcing *One True Way* of accessing the kernel.

The thing is, the mere existence of that class raises a *Big Red Flag*: *because it exists*, and because it's storing a type-level (`static`) kernel instance, it's tremendously easy to have this line of code just about anywhere in the project:

```
var smurf = CompositionRoot.Resolve<ISmurf>();
```

...and you have it, in the `ApplicationShellController` class - and since you've exposed `static` methods, you don't even have to *pass it around as a dependency* ...but it's a *service locator* nonetheless, because `ApplicationShellController` has a *dependency* on the `CompositionRoot` type - i.e. the root isn't at the root anymore!

> ```
> private IDocumentController GetDocumentController(string path)
> {
>     return CompositionRoot.ResolveAll<IDocumentController>()
>         .Cast<IDocumentController>()
>         .Where(provider => provider.Handles(path))
>         .Select(provider => provider)
>         .FirstOrDefault();
> }
> ```

It seems that LINQ bit is more complicated than it should be. `ResolveAll<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so the `Cast<T>` is redundant. Then the `Select` isn't *projecting* anything, and the `Where` could be the predicate for `FirstOrDefault`:

```
return CompositionRoot.ResolveAll<IDocumentController>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(provider => provider.Handles(path));
```

If the intent is to return *one* controller though, and the intent is that there's only ever *one* controller to handle the given `path`, then you should use `.SingleOrDefault` instead of `.FirstOrDefault`, to make the intent clearer (and the method would throw an exception if there's ever two or more controllers for a given path, instead of returning, well, *some random controller of whatever type the thing feels like giving you*).

If I understand your architecture correctly, you don't actually need a new instance of a controller every time this method gets called.

But that's what you're getting.

I think the `ApplicationShellController` constructor should look like this:

```
private readonly IApplicationShellView _view;
private readonly IEnumerable<IDocumentController> _controllers;

public ApplicationShellController(IApplicationShellView view, IEnumerable<IDocumentController> controllers)
{
    _view = view;
    _controllers = controllers;
}
```

Ninject sees the `IEnumerable<IDocumentController>` dependency as an opportunity for a multi-binding: it will automatically resolve an instance of everything that binds to `IDocumentController`, and pass it in.

You don't need the `[Inject]` attribute here. Don't use `[Inject]` attributes. Imagine you have your composition root in a completely different assembly - the only assembly in your solution that *needs* a reference to Ninject, is the assembly with the composition root. Having a dependency on Ninject anywhere else should be forbidden, your code should be written in a completely IoC Container-agnostic way: having an `[Inject]` attribute in your business code suggests that your business code is able to work with an `IKernel` at any given time, and you don't want to give that impression - be it only because in time, the code will be maintained by *someone else* (yes, *future you* is someone else!), and it's always a good idea to send a clear message to that *future maintainer*, that the IoC container lives and dies in its own little corner and doesn't travel anywhere.

Of course there are exceptions... for example you might want to use the `Ninject.Logging` extension and constructor-inject an `ILogger` to any logging-enabled type.

---

So, I'd remove the `CompositionRoot` class, and move the `IKernel` straight to the entry point, reference the *conventions* extension, and do something like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind(t => t.FromThisAssembly()
                      .SelectAllClasses()
                      .BindAllInterfaces());

    FileLogHandler fileLogHandler = new FileLogHandler(Utils.GetLogFilePath());
    Log.LogHandler = fileLogHandler;
    Log.Trace("Program.Main(): Logging initialized");

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(kernel.Get<IApplicationShellView>());
}
```

The [conventions extension](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/wiki/Overview) can do so much more than automagically bind all interfaces in a single instruction though - that was just to illustrate the point that you don't need to manually call `.Bind<ISmurf>()` to explicitly bind every smurf in the village.

For example you could enforce a naming convention in a given namespace, so that anything that doesn't end with "Controller" doesn't bind to `IDocumentController`, for example.

---

Resolving for `IApplicationShellView`, Ninject will get to the `ApplicationShellView` type. And there's a problem:

> ```
> public ApplicationShellView()
> {
>     this.controller = new ApplicationShellController(this);
>     InitializeComponent();
>     InitializeView();
> }
> ```

There's nothing to inject! The view is completely coupled with the concrete controller! But wait, why does the view need to know about its parent controller?

> ```
> private void ribbonButtonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     controller.OpenNewSpreadsheet();
> }
> ```

You need to invert the dependency here (*Inversion of Control* right?), and instead of having the view *asking* the controller to *do something*, have the view *tell* the controller it should to be doing something *because the user clicked a button*.

WinForms is all about events; I'd use an event.

```
public event EventHandler TestButtonClicked;
private void ribbonButtonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = TestButtonClicked;
    handler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Inverting the relationship between the controller and the view has just broken the circular dependency: now all the controller needs to do is handle the view's events!

```
private void shellView_TestButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenNewSpreadsheet();
}
```

Comment: I need some time to read, if I could come back to you later, that would be awesome...

Comment: @Killercam I've cleaned up the comments, just ping me to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36742/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-killercam) whenever you're ready.

Comment: Hi mat, I have now read the "breaking circular dependencies" section. In the above, I don't understand how the controller can "take control" of the event raised in the view without first wiring up the handler in the view itself? Sorry.